# How to prevent ApplePressAndHoldEnabled from turning on?

Tags: keyboard, catalina

How can I prevent "press and hold" from ever becoming enabled?

While typing, occasionally I will type something that activates the press-and-hold "feature", after which I no longer have keyboard repeat.  Instead I have the press-and-hold-for-accent feature enabled.

? What key combo is turning that misfeature on ?

**? How can I prevent it from ever turning on ?**

Once it becomes enabled, I have to go to terminal and `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` to turn it off.  Unfortunately, some apps don't take notice that it has been turned off until after they are closed or the computer is restarted.

Comment: Check Settings> Accessibility > Keyboard.  Disable *slow keys*.  There's no shortcut that enables this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, Slow Keys is already unchecked.